# M.2 is there and not there

Tags: boot

I wanted to up the size of  the m.2 ,on my dell 9343 so I did a backup, but I did something in the config. I can see the m.2 if I boot the usb macrium, but the system can not find it to boot from. and the  bios  now say it is not there. I think I told the ebios to not see it, but I can not remember. I can do  an os install, but the system says no bootable devices. I did a restore defaults but no change. Hardware diagnostics also do no see it. If I put the original m.2 back , the system does not see it, but when I boot from a usb os10, it installs to the disk.

Comment: A lot of mainboards allow to decide for what purpose the PCIex lanes are used. Common targets are a second PCIex16 slot, M.2 slot and additional SATA ports, so you have to decide what is deactivated. Check your BIOS for such an option.

Comment: Undo your changes to the UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: If I knew I would undo, any ideas where to look

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the 9343 is sata mode only, the bigger m2 is not sata mode. So m.2 drives may or may not be sata.

Comment: I think you'll need to wait for a couple of days, but when you can please do accept your answer. If it pops up in a search, the person can then see it contains a solution. Also that moves it out of the Unanswered queue, so it won't pop up as a question three years from now :-)